# php check if specified time has expired

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to compare the current datetime, with a datetime from the database using string, as the following:

```
$today = new DateTime("now");
$todayString = $today->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 

if($todayString >= $rows["PrioritizationDueDate"])
{...}
```

`$todayString` keeps giving me the time 7 hours earlier (i.e now its 11:03pm, its giving me 16:04).

More, is it better to compare this way, or should i compare using datetime objects?

Comment: Try a timestamp its easier to compare

Comment: Are you possibly located 7 hours east of GMT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a correct timezone in the constructor to DateTime.

```
$today = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('TimezoneString'));
```

Where `TimezoneString` is a [valid timezone string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

**Edit:** For a more complete example using DateTime objects, I would use [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/datetime.diff) in conjunction with [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat).

```
$rows["PrioritizationDueDate"] = '2011-11-20 10:30:00';

$today = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$row_date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $rows["PrioritizationDueDate"], new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

if( $row_date->diff( $today)->format('%a') > 1)
{
    echo 'The row timestamp is more than one day in the past from now.';
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vz5OZc)

Answer (score 1):

> $todayString keeps giving me the time 7 hours earlier

you have to setup a timezone for the DateTime object I believe.

> is it better to compare this way

I doubt so.
The general way is to compare in the query, using SQL to do all date calculations and return only matching rows.

Answer (score 0):

First set time zone using this function

```
 date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Then either you can use function strtotime() or get difference directly...